# Android:How to use Roboto special characters?

Tags: android, fonts, textview, special-characters

I don't know how to use some Roboto character in my Textview.
I tried to copy paste character from the character table to eclipse (Roboto is also in my ubuntu), it works for some one but for all...

The greek 'k' works, but the greek 'h' do not print anything, ..
What is the good way to use all special characters in an android project please?

[image: character table]

Comment: "it works for some one but for all... 'k' works, 'h' no, .." -- "no" is a useless description of your symptoms. What, specifically, does "no" mean in the context of your question?

Comment: (edited) 'k' is displayed, but for 'h', 'm', ... nothing is displayed. But I guess copy/paste is tottaly dirty no?

Comment: from my point of view it is not clear what you are really trying to achieve. If you want to use a certain font with your Textview change it's typeface property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use the unicode values of those characters vs copying pasting them from somewhere...

E.g:
Get the unicode value of a character (using LibreOffice for example), and use that in your strings.xml with the '\u' prefix:

```
<string name="special_characters">\u03bb \u03ba \u03bc \u03be - special greek characters</string>
```

See my screenshot (using Roboto-Black.ttf)
[image: Example of Roboto-Black and Greek Characters]